# Getting a syntax error in VSC in Code of Python

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am getting an unexpected error in python while writing code in VSC

```
data = StringVar
lbl = Label(
    root,
    text = "Label",
    anchor = SE,
    font = ("Verdana", 20)
    textvariable = data
    background = "#ffffff",
    fg = "#000000"
)
```

I am getting textvariable line
even I am writing a right code

[I am getting textvariable line
even I am writing a right code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTXPV.png)

[But I am getting a same error if I write different code which is written](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UGp8.png)

Comment: Missing some commas.

Comment: @Loocid If they ask ASAP an answer you should wait at least a day

Comment: @rioV8 Not sure what you mean sorry?

Comment: @Loocid The OP had `ASAP` in his question. If he can't wait for an answer he should find the solution himself by looking at the tooltips of the squiggles. But that is a lot of work and can better be done by somebody else ASAP. Often this is used in Homework assignment questions. If you don't want to learn something choose a different class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing commas (`,`) between some of your arguments:

```py
data = StringVar
lbl = Label(
    root,
    text = "Label",
    anchor = SE,
    font = ("Verdana", 20), # Comma was missing here
    textvariable = data, # and here
    background = "#ffffff",
    fg = "#000000"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply forgot a comma after `font = ("Verdana", 20)` and `textvariable = data`.

Comment: thanks for telling my mistake

Comment: can you help in another code

Comment: yes I can, whats the error?